# Analyse MongoDB's diagnostic.data files

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB crashed and I am trying to understand why. On Ubuntu MongoDB produces files in `/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data`. Those files, e.g. `metrics.2016-03-08T17-15-01Z0`, are binary files.

What tool should I use to analyse MongoDB diagnostic files? What data do the diagnostic files have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe at the moment there is no tool from MongoDB to view this.
Please [see this comment](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22000?focusedCommentId=1121384&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1121384) from MongoDB engineer.

`serverStatus, replSetGetStatus, collStats of local.oplog.rs.stats, buildInfo, getCmdLineOpts, hostInfo` are the data collected as per latest

To understand the data being collected, please head over to [MongoDB source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/ftdc/ftdc_mongod.cpp#L314%7CMongoDB%20source%20code).

Answer (score 7):

You can see the contained data of the `metrics...` files using the tool `bsondump` which is included in every MongoDB installation.

Just execute `bsondump metrics.2016-03-08T17-15-01Z0` and it will print out the decoded content of the file.

Comment: Great, but the decoded content again contains some binary data, how it that decoded?  Just using 64 bit -> UTF-8 decoder does not give anything sensible.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB 3.2 collects server statistics every second (default interval) into the diagnostic files inside the diagnostic.data directory. This data is collected for analysis of MongoDB server's behaviour by MongoDB engineers. I think no tool/document has been released yet for public to analyse the captured data.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the previous comment from @JMax, that you should add the flag --pretty. With this, you will convert the output to a readable format.

Example:
`bsondump --pretty metrics.2023-05-11T14-15-52Z-00000`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34398324)